# Python Need to replace curly bracket with (curly bracket and comma)

Tags: python, json, shell, boto3

I have a JSON response with hundreds of thousands of lines, and all parse from dictionary python and converted to JSON using json.load

Now getting JSON response with invalid response so workaround as follows

**response**

```
{
    "ComplianceType": "",
    "Details": {
        "InstalledTime": "",
        "PatchBaselineId": "",
        "PatchState": ""
    },
    "ExecutionSummary": {
        "ExecutionId": "",
        "ExecutionTime": "",
        "ExecutionType": ""
    },
    "Id": "",
    "ResourceId": "",
    "ResourceType": "",
    "Severity": "",
    "Status": "",
    "Title": ""
}
{
    "ComplianceType": "",
    "Details": {
        "InstalledTime": "",
        "PatchBaselineId": "",
        "PatchState": ""
    },
    "ExecutionSummary": {
        "ExecutionId": "",
        "ExecutionTime": "",
        "ExecutionType": ""
    },
    "Id": "",
    "ResourceId": "",
    "ResourceType": "",
    "Severity": "",
    "Status": "",
    "Title": ""
}
```

**work around to make it valid**

```
[{
    "ComplianceType": "",
    "Details": {
        "InstalledTime": "",
        "PatchBaselineId": "",
        "PatchState": ""
    },
    "ExecutionSummary": {
        "ExecutionId": "",
        "ExecutionTime": "",
        "ExecutionType": ""
    },
    "Id": "",
    "ResourceId": "",
    "ResourceType": "",
    "Severity": "",
    "Status": "",
    "Title": ""
},
{
    "ComplianceType": "",
    "Details": {
        "InstalledTime": "",
        "PatchBaselineId": "",
        "PatchState": ""
    },
    "ExecutionSummary": {
        "ExecutionId": "",
        "ExecutionTime": "",
        "ExecutionType": ""
    },
    "Id": "",
    "ResourceId": "",
    "ResourceType": "",
    "Severity": "",
    "Status": "",
    "Title": ""
}
]
```

These I need to do through the program, when I try using sed shell --> #sed -i 's#}#},#' test.json <-- . this shell command replaces }, in }, and return as },,

```
[{
    "ComplianceType": "",
    "Details": {
        "InstalledTime": "",
        "PatchBaselineId": "",
        "PatchState": ""
    },,
    "ExecutionSummary": {
        "ExecutionId": "",
        "ExecutionTime": "",
        "ExecutionType": ""
    },,
    "Id": "",
    "ResourceId": "",
    "ResourceType": "",
    "Severity": "",
    "Status": "",
    "Title": ""
},
{
    "ComplianceType": "",
    "Details": {
        "InstalledTime": "",
        "PatchBaselineId": "",
        "PatchState": ""
    },,
    "ExecutionSummary": {
        "ExecutionId": "",
        "ExecutionTime": "",
        "ExecutionType": ""
    },,
    "Id": "",
    "ResourceId": "",
    "ResourceType": "",
    "Severity": "",
    "Status": "",
    "Title": ""
},
]
```

Please provide a workaround which works shell or python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your sample input, this might work for you:

```
$ cat input.json \
    | grep -v -e '^[[:space:]]*$' \
    | sed -e '1s/^/[/'   \
          -e '$s/$/]/'   \
          -e 's/^}$/},/'
```

- The `grep` eliminates any blank lines (if any exist).  This is important because the following `sed` needs to operate on the last non-blank line.
- The first `sed` expression adds the `[` to the beginning of the first line
- The second `sed` expression adds the `]` to the end of the last line
- The final `sed` expresison add a comma after any `}` that is on a line by itself

By applying the second `sed` before the third, the last `}` becomes `}]` so that `}` is no longer on a line by itself.

Comment: thank you! this worked like a charm. can I know where can I learn these re ?